# Ubuntu 23.10 - Simple Icons after Switching Dark/Light mode

Tags: icons, screenshot, taskbar, 23.10

I just installed Ubuntu 23.10
After switching between dark and light mode, some of the icons changed to the "simple" version (see screenshot).
Don't know how to change back to the more "beautiful" icons.

Is this a bug?
How to change back?

[image: icons]

Comment: What happens if you first log out then back in? Does that correct the icons?